# React-Typescript Auto-suggest display results after typing three letters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

I created two react-typescript application following NPM **create-react-ts** command,
after that i installed one of the **react-search-box** package for one application then **react-autosuggest** for other application.

Made several modifications but need help on one..I need to include the feature that both the search box should display results in dropdown only after **someone is typing three letters or more.**
For example:- Initially someone types 'A' then results are displayed but now result should be displayed when someone is typing three letters 'TRU' or 'ABC',etc

Any idea how can i make modification to the existing application ??

Below is the structure of my application .....

```
 export class myApp extends React.Component<any,any> {  
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  data: [],
  loading: false
};}
 componentDidMount(){
this.setState({
  loading: true});

fetch('serviceUrl......')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  this.setState({
    data: data.items, 
    loading: false
  });
})}handleChange(event) {
console.log(event);}

  render(){return (
<div className="div_search">
          <Search
            data={ this.state.data }                
            onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this.state.data) }
            placeholder="Enter the name..."
            class="search_box"
            searchKey="fName" 
          />)}
```

fName is the value holidng all firstnames returned from server

Answer (score 2):

You can write logic onChange event and get the current value of input and make state change when your length of input is 3.

Comment: Hi @sureshkumar, yes concept of including onChange event is right are you having any link stating the method you described ?

Comment: Can you provide your code where you getting the result when you typing.

Comment: you can follow this [link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete)

Comment: thanks @sureshkumar its working for me but need help on react-search-box there i am using default 'componentDidMount' to fetch records from service.. followed by onChange any clue how to apply your method on it.!

Comment: @sureshkumar - please look at my post again i included the code, let me know if anything else is required ....

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vomojugobi/edit?js,output

Firstly get response from API in ComponentDidMount and set your response into state then assign that data into items you can refer above link.

Comment: @sureshkumar - can you please tell in your latest fiddle what is 'value'... Trying your logic now i am getting this error - 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'

Comment: @Elizabeth its already in my previous fiddle also. value is using in the ReactAutocomplete, Please check.